# Is there anyway to compare your Storming Stormwind brawl results with other players?

Tags: hearthstone

I would like to know if there is a way to find out how many players were able to inflict more damage than I did yet.

Is there any sort of ranking system to compare stats of this brawl?

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: no, there is no ingame system that lets you compare stats with other players.

Best chance you have is to find a forum and a thread, or start your own, to compare stats with other players.